# Can we create Dataproc Workflow Template by passing a path of Jupyter notebooks in step_id?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

I have been trying to create Dataproc Workflow Template to execute Jupyter notebooks present on my Dataproc cluster but when I instantiate that template the jobs fail whereas if I download my notebooks as `.py` files and then add them to a Workflow Template it works.

I am just curious if there is any way to create a Workflow Template that can directly take in existing Jupyter notebooks as its steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct execution of Jupyter notebooks via Jobs and Workflow Template APIs is not yet supported on Dataproc.

You can workaround this by writing and submitting a PySpark job/Workflow Template step that will use [`nbconvert` to execute a notebook](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html).